# Incomplete Laravel page view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing a web application in Laravel 5, I basically fetch data from database in controller method and pass it the the view which is then shown in a table. When i request that page, sometime complete data is not shown. Like it misses couple of rows randomly, it happens randomly every once in a while, sometime plain html is shown in browser and sometime the script as well, but when i refresh the page it shows complete information on the page properly.
What possible reason can be behind this?

Comment: is error reporting on..?
try these..
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

Comment: i guess u are using php artisan serve...i do encounter the same issue, however for a better development experience try switching to homestead

Comment: That means if the app is deployed on real server, it wont cause any such problems?

Comment: I encountered the same situation few days ago. Refer to my answer below to find the answer. If it helps, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `php artisan serve` command often cause this problem. In a recent past, I encountered the same.

You can get rid of this by setting up your application on a virtual host. I'm using [Laragon](https://laragon.org/) for virtual hosts and the application is working absolutely fine now.